# Why .NET does not parse certain IPv6 with embedded IPv4 values?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, ip-address, ipv6

In my computer, this code:

```
        var someIps = new[]
        {
            "::1.2.3.4",
            "::0000:1.2.3.4",
            "0:0:0:0:0:0:0000:1.2.3.4",
            "1::0000:1.2.3.4",
            "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:1.2.3.4",
            "::abcd:1.2.3.4",
            "0:0:0:0:0:0:abcd:1.2.3.4",
            "1::abcd:1.2.3.4",
            "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:abcd:1.2.3.4",
            "::ffff:1.2.3.4",
            "0:0:0:0:0:0:ffff:1.2.3.4",
            "1::ffff:1.2.3.4",
            "0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:1.2.3.4",
        };

        foreach ( var ip in someIps )
        {
            if (IPAddress.TryParse( ip, out var parsed ))
                Console.WriteLine( "{0} parses to {1}", ip, parsed );
            else
                Console.WriteLine( "{0} does not parse.", ip, parsed );
        }
```

Generates this output:

```
::1.2.3.4 parses to ::1.2.3.4
::0000:1.2.3.4 parses to ::1.2.3.4
0:0:0:0:0:0:0000:1.2.3.4 does not parse.
1::0000:1.2.3.4 parses to 1::102:304
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:1.2.3.4 does not parse.
::abcd:1.2.3.4 parses to ::abcd:102:304
0:0:0:0:0:0:abcd:1.2.3.4 does not parse.
1::abcd:1.2.3.4 parses to 1::abcd:102:304
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:abcd:1.2.3.4 does not parse.
::ffff:1.2.3.4 parses to ::ffff:1.2.3.4
0:0:0:0:0:0:ffff:1.2.3.4 does not parse.
1::ffff:1.2.3.4 parses to 1::ffff:102:304
0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:1.2.3.4 does not parse.
```

Why does it parse `::ffff:1.2.3.4`, but can't parse `0:0:0:0:0:0:ffff:1.2.3.4`? Aren't they supposed to be the same address?

Am I missing something in the IPv6 representation that make those strings invalid? Or did I just find a bug in [IPAddress.TryParse][1] ?

Comment: [This site fails the latter](http://v6decode.com/#address=0%3A0%3A0%3A0%3A0%3A0%3Affff%3A1.2.3.4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mistake in the full written line. It is supposed to be 8 groups of Hex Numbers. 0:0:0:0:0:0:ffff however is only 7 groups - 6 0-groups, 1 f-group

Indeed numbers like these only have 6 groups:
0001:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff - 1 01-group, 4 0-groups, 1 f-group.

Just a classical mistake were repetition seems to have caused you overlooking something.

Comment: Thanks. I just provided a more explanation explicitly citing IPv4 numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I found my mistake. The problem is that the IPv4 in the end takes 2 groups of hex digits in the IPv6 notation, and I intuitively thought it was just one group.

Therefore, terms like `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1.2.3.4`, with 7 groups before the IPv4, would not parse. However, terms like `0:0:0:0:0:0:1.2.3.4`, with just 6 groups parses just fine.